# Tableau Top N set to 10 of group set is showing more than 10

Tags: tableau-api, top-n, group

How can I get top 10 results of my longest rides to date or filter the results to grab distinct string which would be the [Title] of the bike ride? Is there a custom formula I can enter?

My result is showing two results for Ride 1 and Ride 6 which are identical. Therefore I'm getting 12 results instead of 10. As the year goes on, I may repeat a ride and continue to run into this so I'm looking to find a solution that would cover any duplicate titled ride.

on my group set, by field, Top 10 Distance, AVG or MAX   (shows the dupes for two rides)
[image: group set]

On my Top N parameter
I've tried:
By field,
Top 10
Distance
Sum (this shows all rides which is more than 10)

I've done:
By field,
Top 10
Distance
Max (this shows the dupes for two rides)

I've done:
By field,
Top 10
Distance
Avg (this also shows the dupes for two rides)

[image: packed bubbles]

Comment: I've discovered that removing the data from the marks will achieve the result I need but still curious if there is another method so I could show the date as a label? I suppose I'd show all the dates for the duplicate rides or have it show the most recent date when there are dupes.

Comment: ^removing the 'date' from the marks